# Is there any difference?

Tags: differences

Is there any fundamental difference in meaning here?

1. I would understand perfectly if the woman had done something wrong and another woman were blaming her but this isn't the case.
2. I would understand perfectly if the woman did something wrong and another woman were blaming her but this isn't the case.

Comment: Not really. Your English teacher might prefer the first one because it's got a past perfect in it and English teachers seem to consider that an underused construction. Otherwise, they're clear enough.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Your question looks like one that could be easily answered if you asked an English teacher or a friend who spoke English fluently. This site is not a substitute for formal English lessons or practicing with a friend, which makes this question off-topic. If you have tried to answer it using several resources, then please [edit] this to explain how you have tried to answer it yourself and why you're still unsure.

Answer (score 2):

In the examples you provided, the first one is correct as the sentence is reflecting on something that could have happened, requiring it to be written in the subjunctive mood.

"Did" won't work - it's associated with the past tense; something **did** happen.

"Had done" will, and does, work - it's "reflecting" on what **could *have* happened**.

Your second sentence would be used when recounting an event: *The woman **did** something wrong and another woman **was** blaming her.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several possible permutations and to me they are different:

1a. *I would understand perfectly if the woman **had done** [in the past] something wrong and another woman **were** blaming her **[/then/in the past/]** but this **wasn't** the case.*

1b. *I would understand perfectly if the woman **had done** [in the past] something wrong and another woman **were** blaming her **[/now/in the present/]** but this **isn't** the case.*

Both the "doing" (in past time) and the "blaming" (in past or present time) are hypothetical and contrary-to-fact.

2a. *I would understand perfectly if the woman **/did/were to do/** [/now/in present/] something wrong and another woman **were** blaming her **[/now/in the present/]** but this **isn't** the case.*

2b. *I **understand** perfectly **that** the woman **/did/** [in the past] something wrong and another woman **/was/has been/is/** blaming her **[/in the past/in the present/]** but this **isn't** the case.*

2a If "did" is used, 2a contains a backshift to the past to eventually replace the subjunctive "were to do," but the "doing" in present time is still hypothetical.

2b doesn't contain any subjunctive forms and it isn't hypothetical at all - just plain facts, ma'am:-)